# Update information outdated. Apt-get update shows no errors. No automatic updates

Tags: 14.04, updates, notification

Every 8 days i get a red triangle on the menu bar telling me that the update information is outdated.

I don't have any errors when i do a apt-get update or when i try to update using the software updater (gui). Automatic updates are turned off.

This is what happens:

- Red triangle appears.
- I click on the software updater, it checks for updates, it shows the updates available and i press cancel.
- After one minute the red triangle goes away.
- I click on the software updater and i do the the software updates.
- After 8 days or so the red triangle comes back again.

So far i tried:

- disabling and enabling everything on update options.
- Changing the update server.
- deleted everything in /var/lib/apt/periodic and created update-stamp and update-succsess-stamp
- deleted chrome 32-bit repository files from sources.list.d even though i had them disabled on update options.

Does anybody know why this keep happening? Even if i had any errors it shouldn't be looking for updates and telling me that i have update information outdated.

Thanks and sorry for my English.

[apt-get update output](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/294219) - Third reply.

Comment: It would be better if can provide last few lines of the result when you run *sudo apt-get update*

Comment: If the answer has helped you, I would appreciate if you Tick mark it and upvote.

Comment: Hi. Could you tell me how to do it? It says that my comment is too long.

Comment: You can take a screenshot of the result and then add it to your question itself by editing the Question. At end of your question you will find *'edit'* button .

Comment: Hi. Just added it. It's the third reply.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case changing Update Server to "Main Server" solved the issue. But you wrote that you tried this already.

Answer (score 1):

- Every 8th day you are getting that Red warning triangle:
  Possible reason for that is you might have set Update Manager to check for updates Weekly. Though it will not update automatically (Your Auto-Updates are off), it will definitely check and notify you if any updates are available.
- Though your system shows up-to-date status and still you are getting the red triangle might be because you might have installed an application using a **ppa repository** will is no longer supported or broken. You may *disable* that ppa repository and the problem will be resolved.
- If above thing doesn't work try running following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update    --Running fine for you
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer. 1 - I have automatic updates disabled (never) and the rest to display immediately. 2 - The only repository that i added was  Steam. Since apt-get update doesn't show any errors i don't this is the problem. I still have Chrome (32-bit) installed but i removed the repositories. Does this matter? 3 - I never tried the dist-upgrade. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell me how to post the result of apt-get update? It says that is too long

Comment: Hi. I just tried the apt-get dist-upgrade after apt-get upgrade, but there was no difference.

Comment: Then I'll have to work on it. I'll let you know if I come across something productive.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify: There was no difference between upgrade and dist-upgrade on upgrading Ubuntu. Not on the red triangle. The red triangle always disappear for 8 days as soon as i do a apt-get update. Thanks again.